# How to display WP Query filters?

Tags: posts, wp-query, plugin-wpml

I'm wondering if there is a way to display current WP Query filters. I wrote a function that is supported to delete all posts and it does but when I'm using WPML and it filters posts by language then it does not remove non-English posts.

I thought that using `'suppress_filters' => true` will help but will this cause any drawbacks? What other filters are applied to WP Query? Can I display them somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a global variable called `$wp_filter` (you can see examples of it all through [the source of `/wp-includes/plugin.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/plugin.php).  This probably isn't the WordPress Way to do it, but you could try something like this:

```
global $wp_filter;
var_dump( $wp_filter );
```

...but note the caveat on http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables -- "Accessing other globals besides the ones listed below is not recommended."  (And `$wp_filter` isn't in that list.)